# Using jQuery to Popup iFrame from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, iframe

I have inherited some code and I am trying to add an enhancement that will open a [popup](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/popup-iframe/#&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog) style iframe with the URL. The way the code is laid out is there are different `tab-panes` within the html window and in the "content" tab it displays information in the `#post-body` (which is within the content tab). In the content tab one of the pieces of information is a URL.

The code currently looks like this:

HTML:

```
    <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content" style= "height: 100%;">
          <div class="tab-pane" id="top-assoc"></div>
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="top-rank"> </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="top-tags"></div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="content-body-tab" style="height: 100%;">
            <div id="post-body" style="padding: 15px;"> Select a post to preview </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$("#post-body").append($('<div>').addClass("post-view").append(
    [$('<p>').append($('<span>').addClass('bold').text("Post: ")),
        $('<div>', { "style": "font-size: 20px;"}
        ).html(postObj.content),
        $('<div>', { "style": "padding-top: 10px;"})
            .append($('<span>').addClass('bold').text("URL: "))
            .append($('<a>', { "href": postObj.url,
                "target": "_blank" }).html(postObj.url))),
        $('<div>', { "style": "padding-top: 10px;"})
            .append($('<p>', { "style": "overflow-wrap: break-word"})
                .append($('<span>').addClass('bold').text("Users: "))...morecode
```

So what I did to change this is I added a `div` to the html and an `onclick` function to the javascript. Which looks like

HTML:

```
      <div class="tab-pane" id="content-body-tab" style="height: 100%;">
        <div id="post-body" style="padding: 15px;"> Select a post to preview </div>
        <div id="post-frame" data-role="popup"><iframe id="framecontent" src="" width="80%" height="500"></iframe></div>
      </div>
```

JS:

```
 $('<div>', { "style" : "padding-top: 10px;"})
 .append($('<span>').addClass('bold').text("URL: "))
 .append($('<a>', { "href": postObj.url,
                    "target" : "_blank" }).html(postObj.url)).on("click", function() {
         $(#framecontent).attr("src", postObj.url);
     }),
```

Which I think should work, but I am getting an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` according to the chrome browser console which is hitting on `$(#framecontent).attr("src", postObj.url);`

I am not sure why this is not working? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(#framecontent).attr("src", postObj.url);
```

needs to be

```
$('#framecontent').attr("src", postObj.url);
```

If you don't understand why, go check http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

It can be an other thing too, but without a complete code it's hard to figure what.

Comment: Ahhh I missed something simple like that. However, it is giving me a `Refused to display 'https://www.samplelink.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.` error. Does iFrame not work in all browsers?

Comment: Look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options I'm not familiar with iframe's configuration but it seems that, in your case, you can't call a url from an other domain.